# backbone.js JSON parse error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, backbone.js, cors

Alright, I'm new to Backbone.js, and am just trying to get a simple collection fetch working.

On the server side, I'm sending the following JSON I've verified that this comes down in the response body:

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"last_name":"Smith","first_name":"Bob","date_of_birth":"1980-01-06T05:00:00Z","created_at":"2013-04-26T00:50:00Z","updated_at":"2013-04-26T00:50:00Z"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"last_name":"Smith","first_name":"Roger","date_of_birth":"1985-01-01T05:00:00Z","created_at":"2013-04-27T04:00:00Z","updated_at":"2013-04-27T04:00:00Z"}]
```

This passes JSONLint

I've got my server running at localhost:8080 in a Jetty (Scala/Scalatra), and my client side stuff being served out of nginx running at localhost:8083.  I *think* I've got CORS support working correctly.  In any case, I'm getting a 200 response along with my JSON.

The Request looks like this (Opera dev console):

```
GET /api/persons HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8083/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: http://localhost:8083
```

The Headers in the response are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8083
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server: Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)
```

This was tripping my fetch's error callback.  So, next I wrote a regular jquery $.getJSON(), then the same req in $.ajax form.  No luck.

I finally added some checks in an $.ajaxSetup (oh, coffeescript, btw):

```
$.ajaxSetup 
  error: (jqXHR, exception) ->
    if jqXHR.status == 0
      alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.')
    else if jqXHR.status == 404
      alert('Requested page not found. [404]')
    else if jqXHR.status == 500
      alert('Internal Server Error [500].')
    else if exception == 'parsererror'
      alert('Requested JSON parse failed.')
    else if exception == 'timeout'
      alert('Time out error.')
    else if exception == 'abort'
      alert('Ajax request aborted.')
    else
      alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText)
```

The 'parsererror' is being triggered.  So, huh.  I'm missing something obvious, I know it.

Comment: I'd start by checking that the [CORS is activated on jQuery too by using the `xhrField.withCredentials` setting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: What shows your browser console? Please copy the errors with whole stack trace. Probably it will be helpful. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-exceptions

Comment: @SimonBoudrias, Thank you.  Adding jqXHR.withCredentials = true to my $.ajaxPrefilter fixed it.  Put that in an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: There you go, wasn't sure my answer was right as there was some missing information. I'm happy to know it wasn't anything harder than that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that the [CORS is activated on jQuery too by using the `xhrField.withCredentials` setting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).